# Performance indicator gem for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, activeadmin

I'm looking for a gem for Rails that helps to monitor the performance of a platform. It needs to be able to monitor key performance indicators of the platform. Stuff like the number of users gained each day, the number of users that left the platform. 
I found the library of [Sevos](https://github.com/sevos/kpi) that looks quite nice, but it leaves me wondering if there are other tools that can easily be integrated with active_admin. With a more graphic way of showing the performance of the platform.

Comment: This seems easy enough to add as a custom panel on your ActiveAdmin dashboard

Answer (score 0):

I think http://www.newrelic.com could be interesting for you. I haven't tested it yet but it looks promising and I've heard from some other people that they use it for their apps. you can find the ruby agent on https://github.com/newrelic/rpm

Comment: I'm using new relic for finding out performance bottlenecks. But that does not give information about strategic problems. How many users are active? How many users signed up today?

Comment: oh ok. well, if you just need data like registrations per day i would follow Kyle Macey's advice. The ActiveAdmin dashboard is perfect for that.